# Python Code to Merge Two Dataframes

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I need to automate a Python code to merge two dataframes. The code should take dataframe1, dataframe2, type of join (left,right or inner), key column name as arguments.

The original code looks like follows:

```
df_merge=merge_data(df4,df5,"left","ID")
```

I need to call the function and input the arguments to execute the code.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. Also please format your code as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [pandas.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) no need to define a new function;

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df4, df5, how='left', on=["ID"]) # default is inner
```